# Как сделать загрузку Windows XP из .img?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Как правильно прописать в загрузку Windows XP из D:\xp.img (на реальном железе без qemu)?

Answer (score 2):

Просто - никак, потому что для того, чтобы форточка загрузилась, нужно заставить работать ее загрузчик. А загрузчик ждет, что его запустят из нулевого сектора диска (и далее, он будет читать `ntoskernel` и его друзей с диска, а не из файлика), а не откуда попало.

Так что проще записать содержимое образа на диск и загружатья с него.

Comment: Строго говоря, можно это сделать. Самый простой вариант использовать другой загрузчик, для старта подключения загрузчика из файла-образа. Часто встречал реализацию на всяких BootCD и т.п. Вот пример реализации для [grub](https://superuser.com/questions/412028/).

Comment: Похоже, что в том ответе речь идет только про Linux

Comment: это сугубо технические детали, где будет  развернута Windows XP: из монтируемого образа,на разделе NTFS/FAT, будет это WinPE или нет, и пр. Вопрос был о процессе загрузке, соответстенно, ссылка дана именно на рабочий конфиг, где реализована загрузка с файла образа.

Comment: В приведенном вами ответе речь идет про загрузку Linux из образа в файле. Ничего про загрузку Windows из образа в файле там нет. Это в Linux можно легко подсунуть файл в качестве диска через loopback-устройство, и все будет нормально работать.

Comment: Ну если понимать вопрос как **запустить** систему XP с файла снятого образа диска (а не как запустить процесс загрузки Windows XP), то конечно же соглашусь с Вами: просто - никак. Если же речь о специально подготовленных образах типа WIM для режимов Windows PE, то можно поискать в теме про GRUB4DOS и т.п.

Comment: Да, я именно из этого и рассуждаю - автор хочет грузиться из файлика на железе и в этом файлике работать.